# script for barcode scanner to fill in appropriate fields

Tags: filemaker

I am making a filemaker pro layout and need help with scanning from a barcode reader (in keyboard emulation mode). My barcodes have two bits of data on them: a user ID and the title of a document the barcode is attached to.

My end goal of my script is to be able to scan a barcode and output the barcode's data into the appropriate field (eg. the title of the document).

Here is what I currently have. It doesnt work, but this is what I was able to find from googling. I also attached the script to the appropriate field from the "Script Triggers" options to respond to "OnObjectKeystroke" but that still doesnt make it work.

Here is my code:

```
If [ Code (Get(TriggerKeystroke)) = "user1_paper1"]
    Set Field [user data::user1 ; "paper1"]
    Insert from Device [user data::user1 ; Type: Bar Code; 
    Camera: Back; Resolution: Full]
End If
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Code (Get(TriggerKeystroke))` returns the ASCII code for a SINGLE keyed-in character and will never match your string. Try the script without the IF clause to see if you script trigger fires properly. I would expect it will not work as you wish, as OnObjectKeystroke will fire for each character in the string. Try the OnObjectModify or OnObjectValidate trigger.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. Is there a way to put information in a field from a script without having a field selected? Thanks

Comment: Yes, several ways. Set Field is probably the best, as the field does not even have to be on the layout. Also check out Insert, Go to Field and Go to Object.